# How to dynamically create event listeners and their functions for dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I dynamically create a number of rows in a table.
Each row has seven columns with the same controls in each columns.
1st column is a toggle meant to disable the textboxes or dropdowns in the other six columns.
How can I dynamically create the event listeners and their respective functions to give each toggle their intended behaviour?
[image: What it looks like...]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Here is the solution,

```
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const toggleRow = event.target.closest('tr');
    const textboxes = toggleRow.querySelectorAll('.textbox');
    const dropdowns = toggleRow.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

    if (toggle.checked) {
      textboxes.forEach(textbox => textbox.setAttribute('disabled', true));
      dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => dropdown.setAttribute('disabled', true));
    } else {
      textboxes.forEach(textbox => textbox.removeAttribute('disabled'));
      dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => dropdown.removeAttribute('disabled'));
    }
  });
});
```

- Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDetailsElement/toggle_event) to view detailed explanation about EventListeners.

*hope you will get an idea about the code...*

Comment: Big thank you, Peter. I'm 46 and I'm 25 years late into this. However, never too late to give a start! Cheers from Vancouver :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm happy to hear that you've started to learn. It's never too late to pursue new interests and abilities, regardless of age. Good luck with your studies and have fun in Vancouver!